# Ghost {{@blog.url}} port with mod_proxy and apache

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, ghost-blog

I'm running ghost blog with apache front of it. I using a reverse proxy to port from 80 to local port. This is working correctly but the {{@blog.url}} tag returns hyperlink which has the local port. So once I click a link generated by @blog.url I'm having url with the local port.

How can I get rid of this?

My VirtualHost config from httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyVia Off
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my node.js ghost config.js:

```
// # Ghost Configuration
// Setup your Ghost install for various environments

var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Development **(default)**
    development: {
        // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and emai                                            l.
        url: 'http://domain.com',

                mail: {
                    transport: 'SMTP',
                    options: {
                        service: 'Gmail',
                        auth: {
                            user: 'email@gmail.com',
                            pass: 'password'
                                 }
                            }
                        },

        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode se                                            t this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '8080'
        }
    },

    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://my-ghost-blog.com',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode se                                            t this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        }
    },

    // **Developers only need to edit below here**

    // ### Testing
    // Used when developing Ghost to run tests and check the health of Ghost
    // Uses a different port number
    testing: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-test.db')
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        }
    },

    // ### Travis
    // Automated testing run through GitHub
    'travis-sqlite3': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-travis.db')
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        }
    },

    // ### Travis
    // Automated testing run through GitHub
    'travis-mysql': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'travis',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_travis',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        }
    },

    // ### Travis
    // Automated testing run through GitHub
    'travis-pg': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'postgres',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_travis',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        }
    }
};

// Export config
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo $NODE_ENV` and show how you start Ghost?

Comment: I restarted the ghost and it resolved the problem.